# How do I access my Application from a custom ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android

How I usually access my Application:

```
MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication)this.getApplication();
```

but this can't be done from

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SomeObject> {}
```

because getApplication() is an activity method. Is there a way to access the Application from an ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, your application should be singleton of your program. So, the easiest way to do this is to make a static reference of your application object.

```
class MyApp extends Application {
    static MyApp myAppInstance;
    public MyApp() {
        myAppInstance = this;
    }
    public static MyApp getInstance() {
        return myAppInstance;
    }
}
```

Then in your adapter you can just call MyApp.getInstance()

Comment: I like this, seems like a much more convenient way to access application instance anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, you can unaccept the former answer and adopt mine if you think this is a better choice.

Answer (score 5):

If you create a constructor for your Adapter that asks for the calling activity to pass a MyApplication parameter, you could then use that object. For example:

```
private MyApplication myApp;

public void MyArrayAdapter(MyApplication app){
    myApp = app;
    //do other setup stuff here
}
```

Then, to create the adapter in the activity you could do something like:

```
MyArrayAdapter myAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this.getApplication());
```

Answer (score 0):

We normally pass the context of activity to custom array adapter. From that context use can call Application stuff.

```
MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication)context.getApplication();
```